Chakra UI Button _before Pseudo-Element Appears On Top Instead of Behind the Button
I'm trying to create a custom button in Chakra UI with a _before pseudo-element that appears as an outline behind the button. However, the pseudo-element keeps appearing on top of the button rather than behind it.
import { defineStyle } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const baseStyle = defineStyle({
  fontWeight: "500",
  fontFamily: "header",
  borderRadius: "0.62rem",
});

const primary = defineStyle((props) => {
  const { custombg, customcolor, effect = true } = props;

  return {
    bg: custombg ?? "black",
    color: customcolor ?? "white",
    borderRadius: "base",
    px: 8,
    py: 3,
    fontSize: "md",
    fontWeight: "normal",
    position: "relative",
    zIndex: 10,
    _before: effect
      ? {
          content: '""',
          position: "absolute",
          top: ".6rem",
          left: ".2rem",
          right: "-0.3rem",
          bottom: "-0.45rem",
          bg: "transparent",
          border: "3px solid black",
          borderRadius: "base",
          zIndex: -10,
        }
      : {},
    _active: {
      top: effect ? ".6rem" : 0,
      left: effect ? "0.2rem" : 0,
      right: effect ? "-0.3rem" : 0,
      bottom: effect ? "-0.45rem" : 0,
      _before: {
        border: "none",
      },
    },
    _disabled: {
      bg: "gray.900",
      _before: {
        border: "none",
      },
      pointerEvents: "none",
    },
  };
});

Issue:
Despite setting the zIndex of the _before pseudo-element to -10 and the main button content to 10, the _before pseudo-element still appears on top of the button content instead of behind it.
Questions:
Why does the _before pseudo-element appear on top of the button content despite setting the zIndex?
How can I ensure the _before pseudo-element appears behind the main button content?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
